# How to join two stable in tdengine

Tags: tdengine

I want to join to stable in tdengine. But I tried couple of time, which will always make a mistake. I was exhausted,can some help me find out what was the mistake that I had made?

```
select t1.* from meter2 t2, meters t1 where t1.ts = t2.ts;

select t1.* from meter2 t2, meters t1 where t1.ts = t2.ts and t1.location = t2.location;

select t1.* from meter2 t2, meters t1 where t1.ts = t2.ts and t1.location = t2.location and t1.groupId = t2.groupId;

select t1.* from meter2 t2 inner join  meters t1 on t1.ts = t2.ts;

select t1.* from meter2 t2 inner join  meters t1 on t1.ts = t2.ts and t1.location = t2.location ;
```

The error throw by tdengine client are as the follow picture.[image: execution errors]

Answer (score 0):

I think TDengine provides the join syntax based on the timestamp column only, not support join the ordinary columns yet. For super table join condition you need to include tags.